# How to get abstract dependent properties to work

Tags: oop, matlab, inheritance, properties, abstract-class

I would like to define an interface with properties in an abstract class like this

```
classdef A
    properties (Abstract = true)
        Valid;
    end
end
```

with an implementation of this interface like this

```
classdef B < A
    properties (Dependent = true)
        Valid;
    end
    methods
        function v = get.Valid(obj)
            v = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

but when I try to make an instance of B I get the following error

```
>> c = B()
??? Error using ==> B
The property 'Valid' restriction defined in class 'B' must match the property definition in base class 'B'.
```

Can anyone tell me what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `Dependent` property attribute in the base class as well:

```
classdef A
    properties (Abstract = true, Dependent = true)
        Valid;
    end
end
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brgxk22-1.html#brjh54r-1):

> Concrete subclasses must redefine abstract properties without the
>   Abstract attribute set to true

The way I understood this, subclass property attributes must match the base class (without the `Abstract` property)

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solves the problem. I guess I was thrown by the documentation not mentioning the `Dependent` attribute in the phrase _... without the Abstract attribute set to true and must use the same values for SetAccess and GetAccess attributes as the base class._